# Should I cache a X509Certificate2 as a static variable of an ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, x509

What's your opinion on this? Should I just load a X509Certificate2 from the store and keep in memory (say, in a static variable) while the web app is running or should I load it (and dispose it) on demand? I'm thinking about going with number 1, but I'm not sure if there's anything related with the way X509Certificate2 works that might make it a bad option...

**EDIT**: I'm using the certificate for signing SAML2 messages which are being used for authentication

Thanks.

Luis

Comment: For what purposes you are using certificate in your web app?

Comment: Hello @Crypt32. I've edited the message to clarify it.